# How to find Current Location' Latitude Longitude

Tags: android, gps

I want to develope an app in which when i start the app it will first give me Latitude and Longitude of my current location. Here is my code:

```
   LocationListener locLis=new LocationListener() {

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}      
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}           
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}  
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Double lat=location.getLatitude();
   Double lon=location.getLongitude();
   Log.i("Latitude=="+lat,"=="+lon);

}
};
 locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, locLis);
```

I use `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in the manifest file. 
But when i start the app there is no latitude and longitude it found. Why? If i change the location's latitude longitude from the command prompt then it will show the updated latitude and longitude. Please anyone help me

Comment: what do you mean be "if I change the location's latitude longitude from the command prompt" - are you testing that app on the emulator only? then this is your only choice, the emulator does not have a gps chip :-) - if you are testing on a real device make sure gps is on and you are near a window or even better outside

Comment: At first i tried in emulator Then i tried in my device (HTC desire) but their is no results.

Answer (score 1):

**Take this code and enjoy**

public void find_Location(Context con)
    {
        Log.d("Find Location", "in find_location");
        this.con=con;
        String location_context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager)con.getSystemService(location_context);

```
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
   for (String provider : providers) 
   {
       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,new LocationListener()
       {
           public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
           public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
           public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
           public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle  extras){}
       });
       Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
       if (location != null)
       {
           latitude = location.getLatitude();
           longitude = location.getLongitude();
           addr=ConvertPointToLocation(latitude,longitude);
                   String temp_c=SendToUrl(addr);

       } 
   }
}

public String ConvertPointToLocation(double pointlat,double pointlog) {

    String address = "";
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(con,
            Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(pointlat,pointlog, 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0)
                    .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return address;
}
```

Comment: Add user permission in over appcation                                  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is set to display the location only when it changes.
I think in order to display it when the app starts, you should try putting it in onProviderEnabled() or some other initialization routine.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this

```
            public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {}

            @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {}
            @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {}
             @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {

    }
       }
     mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

     mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

Comment: test it on a real device and use toast in the methods to get lat and long displayed

Comment: in settings, is the GPS location checkbox turned to checked?

Comment: when i used GPS to get location updates on HTC desire, it took 3 to 4 mins to get first location update. and if i didnt have a clear sky above me it would take 10 mins or even more to get first location update and if im inside a building it would take forever.you can also use Criteria crta = new Criteria();
  crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
  crta.setAltitudeRequired(false);
  crta.setBearingRequired(false);
  crta.setCostAllowed(false);
  crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);